# redirect_uri issue in REST based oAuth2 request

Tags: wordpress, oauth

I am getting this in response

> The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the 'WEB' client type. You can create a Client ID for native application at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient

for:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters&client_id=____.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code&approval_prompt=force&access_type=offline

from my WordPress dashboard.

Searched a lot and tried variations but can't resolve the idea of native app vs web app. Can someone please provide me some clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this information is helpful, but what I can say is that the difference between native applications and web applications is mentioned in "[2. Client Metadata](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html#ClientMetadata)" of [OpenID Connect Dynamic Client Registration 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-registration-1_0.html) as follows:

> **application_type**
>
> OPTIONAL. Kind of the application. The default, if omitted, is `web`. The defined values are `native` or `web`. Web Clients using the OAuth Implicit Grant Type MUST only register URLs using the `https` scheme as `redirect_uris`; they MUST NOT use `localhost` as the hostname. Native Clients MUST only register `redirect_uris` using custom URI schemes or URLs using the `http:` scheme with `localhost` as the hostname. Authorization Servers MAY place additional constraints on Native Clients. Authorization Servers MAY reject Redirection URI values using the `http` scheme, other than the `localhost` case for Native Clients. The Authorization Server MUST verify that all the registered `redirect_uris` conform to these constraints. This prevents sharing a Client ID across different types of Clients.

Also, see "[9. Native Applications](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-9)" in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749).

I recommend you to ask Google about how to specify the **application type** of your client application.

Comment: Thank you for help. I am actually looking to create a native app through Google console but what I get is option for web app.